# grpc testing with mock testify - needs to make 1 more call

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, grpc

I'm trying to implement tests with testify mock but I'm receiving the error:

`The code you are testing needs to make 1 more call(s).`

my test:

```
func TestLoginWithRefreshToken(t *testing.T) {

    profileRepository := new(mocks.ProfileRepository)
    profileRepository.On("GetByIdpID", ctx, "foda").Return(nil, nil)
    sServer := &Sserver{}
    block, _ := sServer.LoginWithRefreshToken(ctx,
        &authpb.TokenRequest{AccessToken: refreshToken},
    )
    profileRepository.AssertExpectations(t)
    if block.Message != "User Blocked" {
        t.Error("Expected 'User Blocked', got", block.Message)
    }
}
```

And my tested function is like:

```
func (s *Sserver) LoginWithRefreshToken(ctx context.Context, request *authpb.TokenRequest) (*authpb.LoginResponse, error) {

    ...

    if claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok && token.Valid {
        idpID := claims["idp_id"].(string)

        profile, err := s.ProfileRepo.GetByIdpID(ctx, idpID)
        if err != nil {
            return &authpb.LoginResponse{
                Message: err.Error(),
                Success: false,
            }, nil
        }

    ...

        tokenResponse, err := m.GenerateTokens(profile, &dtos.IDPAuthResponseDTO{
            LocalID: profile.IdpId,
        })
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return nil, err
        }

        return &authpb.LoginResponse{
            Message:      "OK",
            Success:      true,
            Token:        tokenResponse.AccessToken,
            RefreshToken: tokenResponse.RefreshToken,
            UserData:     handlers_utils.ParseProfileStruct(tokenResponse.UserData),
        }, nil

    }
    return nil, nil
}
```

and the `GetByIdpID` is actually been called instead of getting mocked.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the created `profileRepository`. Did you mean to use `sServer := &Sserver{ProfileRepo: profileRepository}`?

Comment: @Brits this profileRepository its a mocked one...cant use it on sServer...I will need to mock the Sserver and the LoginWithRefreshToken ?

Comment: Mocking the whole `Sserver` would not really leave anything to test. Currently you are creating a mock but not actually using it (the mocked function will never be called). If `ProfileRepo` is an interface then you can use something like [mockery](https://github.com/vektra/mockery) to generate a full mock for you. There are other options but they involve editing your code to allow injection of the mocked `profileRepository` (note that as you have only provided parts of your code this involves some guesses).